# Role of shared gaze/joint attention in infants for the development of executive function

Tags: cognitive-psychology, developmental-psychology, cognitive-development

I'm trying to find research on the role of interactions between caregiver and infant via shared gaze/joint attention for the development of executive abilities, including attention and inhibition. My assumption is that joint attention serves as an externally guided precursors of later self-generated executive abilities as might be postulated based on Vygotsky. References or comments would be most welcome